# Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am getting this kind of error, how to fix it.

```
Error:Unable to load class 'org.gradle.tooling.internal.protocol.test.InternalTestExecutionConnection'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

Comment: Please check my answer. In my case it was JDK path issue. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44583007/3265444

Comment: the problem occurs when internet disconnects in the middle of your gradle download. so go to the C:\Users\your username\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.5-bin and delete the zip file. Reopen the project and gradle will start to download 100mb file again.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

I updated my Android Studio to 2.3 and it asked me to update my gradle plugin to 3.3 that created issues with my running projects. 
I've gone through all the Stack solutions and nothing worked for me except this workaround:
**I changed my distribution url in gradle-wrapper.properties with this one.**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```

(permanent link list here : https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)

My project is up and running.It just asked me to update to **gradle build tools 25.0.0** which I did so. Everything is fine now :)

1. Go to the project section  and select gradle scripts menu.
2. Under script, menu select gradle -wrapper.properties
3. Then replace the distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip with "distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.4.1-all.zip"

[image]
note: **distributions gradle will change depended upon the version of the android studio.**

Comment: Perfect solution, worked for me after days of search. Thanks.

Comment: Where gradle-wrapper.properties found? All I see is a jar file

Comment: It's in your project's Gradle folder hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks! But the problem persists after initializing every new project. It there a permanent fix?

Comment: For anyone updating this in the future, the list of Gradle versions can be found here: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ Just right click and save link location to use the String in your gradle file.

Comment: gradle-6.2.2-all.zip fixed the issue for Android Studio 3.6.1

Comment: If someone find it difficult to get the version number, here's a simple trick that will work for you. Just create a new project, Go to its gradle-wrapper.properties file and copy the version from there.

Answer (score 69):

Make sure you have Internet Connection then:

1.***For Window Users*** Go to `> C:\Users\username\.gradle\wrapper\dists`

2.***For Linux users***
Go to `$HOME/.gradle (~/.gradle)` and/or (Under Specific project) 
  `<PROJECT_DIR>/.gradle`

3.Delete the gradle file(s) with the problem(i.e the zipped folders with 
  missing with no its extracted file )

4.Sync the project with gradle files.

Comment: In my case, the internet cut out while downloading Gradle. Clicking "Try Again" did nothing (on Android Studio 3.1.3). Deleting the ``C:\Users\username\.gradle\wrapper\dists`` folder did fix it and allow it to download again.

Answer (score 27):

## Delete corrupt files

This error occurs when Gradle files are not completely downloaded or corrupted by some other reason, so we have to redownload the files.
The easy way is to delete the old files in

### **`C:\Users\username.gradle\wrapper\dists`**

and rebuild the project, Android Studio will automatically download the new files.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it was always failing to download with me, so even if i changed the version, that wouldn't help, but deleting the files and trying  again, worked, thanks.

Comment: In my case, it did not work. I tried to delete the files still I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 14):

Watch the Tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u92_73vfA8M

or

follow steps :

1. Go to any browser
2. type gradle and press enter

you can specify any version you want after the

gradle keyword

i am downloading gradle 3.3

3. https://services.gradle.org/distributions
   click on this link which is in description directly if you want
4. click on gradle 3.3 all.zip
5. wait for the download to complete
6. once the download is complete 
   extract the file to the location

c://user/your pc name /.gradle/wrapper/dists

7. wait till extraction it takes 5 mins to complete
8. Now open your project in android studio

9.go to file > settings >bulid ,exec,deployment > gradle

10. now change use default gradle to

use local gradle distributn

select the location where you had extracted gradle 3.3.zip

C:\Users\your pc name.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-3.3

11. click on OK
12. Now build starts again and

you can see now the build is successful and error is resolved

Comment: this answer should cover every flow of the problem

Comment: Why do we need the browser?

Comment: to download the gradle file locally for the subsequent builds locally

Answer (score 7):

If you manually setup gradle also make sure projects build.gradle verison is compatible with it. See following as an example.

**Project's build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    }
```

**Manual gradle setup**

[image: Manual gradle setup]

Answer (score 7):

A lot of answer to this questions but a few were helping. I want to give accurate and updated answer.

> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

This error happens when you bad internet connection or you put your computer to sleep while Android Studio is downloading the required dependencies.

How to resolve this issue.

1. Find out the project's Gradle version. You will find that in `gradle-wrapper.properties` in `distributionUrl` my gradle distribution was `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip` that means `gradle-6.5-all.zip` is required to download and right now it is corrupted because of connection timeout. Lets find out this folder and delete this.
2. Go to `$HOME/.gradle` folder then to `wrapper` then to `dists` then find a folder that matches the gradle version name that required to download. In my case it was `gradle-6.5-all.zip` select this folder and delete it.
3. Now sync the project and make sure you have good internet connection and setting that will prevent your system going to sleep while downloading something.

Comment: The only answer that doesn't mess with the generated gradle files

Comment: This is right answer .

Answer (score 6):

Kindly delele all folders under the in /.graddle/version/

This is how i solved mine. good luck

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can run `./gradlew build -s` in the terminal, the stacktrace would show you where went wrong.

Comment: In my case, I found that one of my repositories failed, causing gson dependency download failed

Comment: This command help me find the correct corrupted gradle file.

Answer (score 4):

**Try the next step to "Refresh" your IDE (android studio)**

1. Let Gradle rebuild your auto-genrated files by click **Build | Rebuild** 
 
2. Also try [Choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/cleaning-system-cache.html)

Comment: If doesn't work - Please provide your Gradle logs after doing this.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this issue by downloading current version of graddle from link given
[download latest version of graddle possibly graddle 3.3](https://gradle.org/gradle-download/)

Then in next step i accessed .graddle/wrapper/dists dirctory from home directory on my Mac after showing up hidden system files and deleted previuos version folder residing there.

Now i put that downloaded latest version folder after uncompressing there.
Now restarted Android studio and problem was resolved.

Answer (score 3):

i deleted the **gradle** folder and then i did rebuild, every thing working fine

Answer (score 3):

If you are seeing this error in Android Studio 4.1 with Gradle 6.5 then you should move back to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
```

For some reason

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
```

does not work correctly.

Comment: Thank You. its working. classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"

Comment: In my case I actually needed to change it to 4.2.0. My build.grade file was still set at 3.4 after updating Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

1. first Open your Android Studio  > open any project you're doing
2. click on File > Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Gradle
3. At Project-Level settings , there are 2 option to sync the gradle either usin the default or local.
4. now change from default to a local gradle distribution > gradle Home
5. select the path on your computer.

> C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-4.1

6. click on OK
7. Now build starts again  it should be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Go to "C:\Users\.gradle\caches\". Delete all the files in the folder. Then Sync Gradle and Rebuild the project.

Comment: thank you. at least 4 hours I tried to solve this problem, every solution on stackoverflow is failed except this.

Answer (score 2):

If you using Ubuntu, So firstly you have unhide all files from your home directory or where located your android studio folder :

1. Go to your home directory and unhide all files by using **ctrl+h**
2. You found **.gradle** folder
3. Inside .gradle -> wrapper
4. You can found **dists** folder, So delete this ***dists*** folder
5. Create a New Project than your Gradle file re-downloaded
6. Congo you successfully build project

Answer (score 1):

check out distributionUrl setting in gradle-wrapper.properties. I changed https to http, then my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,just change http to https in the gradle-wrapper and  Sync  it.

Answer (score 1):

Just reimport project. :)
I tried cleaning up the cache and refreshing dependencies doesn't work but failed.

Comment: I had to delete and re-import my modules

Answer (score 1):

Clear .gradle folder and rebuild

Answer (score 1):

1. Open C:\Users\Username.gradle\wrapper\dists\
2. Open latest gradle folder, e.g. *gradle-4.1-rc-1-all*

   You will find a random folder named *936kh1brdchce6fvd2c1o8t8x*
3. Download zip file of similar name

   eg: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip
4. Save it in this folder
5. Restart Android studio

   It will automatically extract the zip folder and Error will clear

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this problem.

If you just copy new version's files to old folder and override files,you may face the same question as me.

To solve it:

1. makesure you saved your all settings.
2. close AS,**DELETE ALL** files of your mixed version.
3. extract new version to your empty folder.

It works for me.

Comment: Worked for me. App was being deployed through Self-Service which didn't bother to first clear out the old directory. Requesting them to do so fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For me, i was cloning a project from github which used a version of gradle higher than that which i had installed. I had two choices:

1. Open gradle.wrapper-properties of a project you have that's building successfully, and copy the line that says `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`. Use this to replace the same value in the project that's failing. That should do the trick.
2. Your build might still fail if the gradle version used to build the project is higher than that which you just added. For this you should update the gradle version to the latest.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I hade to change from:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    **apply plugin :'com.google.gms.google-services'**
}
```

to

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. search on google "download java 11"
2. click oracle website download your java to your platform  and install it.
3. go to android studio click CTRL+SHIFT+ALT(Project Structure)
4. SDK Location Tab Show the path of JDK location which you installed[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

This won't download and always gives 'gradle cache corrupt' error, but a small change makes it work fine

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Now sync the gradle again and it's done.

Answer (score 1):

I will generalize the issue that you might face

Inside `module's` `build.gradle`  :

Change:

```
plugins {
    [...]
    apply plugin:'whatever_you_have'
}
```

to

```
plugins {
    [...]
    id 'whatever_you_have'
}
```

**In other words instead of `apply plugin:` use `id`**

Answer (score 1):

> Unable to find method ''void
> com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTest$default(com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension,
> com.android.build.api.extension.VariantSelector,
> kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)'' 'void
> com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension$DefaultImpls.androidTest$default(com.android.build.api.extension.AndroidComponentsExtension,
> com.android.build.api.extension.VariantSelector,
> kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1, int, java.lang.Object)'
>
> Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after
> a network connection timeout.)
>
> Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network) The state
> of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle
> daemons may solve this problem.
>
> Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart) Your project may be
> using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other
> plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
> project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the
> IDE and then killing all Java processes.

It happened to me after upgrading Android Studio to 4.2.0.

Updating the hilt classpath on build.gradle to 2.35 fixed these issues for me.

```
classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$2.35"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to answer this question, but after searching for so long and checking each and every dependency the problem with me was I've promoted the Kotlin version but forgot to update the KSP version,

```
id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.8.20-1.0.11'
```

Please make sure this line should contain the same version as your Kotlin version

***Hope this helps!***

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated your android studio, then go to FILE, Project Structure, Project, then check gradle version. Before that check your gradle version in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle and check the version if it matches then sync again else change the gradle version in android studio and sync again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after cloning [AnySoftKeyboard](https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard) and opening it in Android Studio. What worked for me was deleting the `AynSoftKeyboard/gradle` folder and then cleaning the project via menu item `Build > Clean Project`.

So try deleting `YourProject/gradle` folder and clean the project to trigger a Gradle sync.

Hope it works for your case.

Answer (score 0):

download **gradle** from [here](https://gradle.org/releases) for your OS and extract the file and paste the inner folder into installLocation/gradle

than in Android Studio Goto File > Settings > bulid ,exec,deployment  > gradle and choose local gradle option and provide the file path of your new downloaded gradle and hit ok it works :)

Answer (score 0):

1. delete C:\Users\Administrator.gradle\caches\xxx (xxx gradle version)
2. rebuild

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem i just deleted every thing related to android in 
c://user/your pc name /
and it worked

Comment: i had the same problem and just deleted everything but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

If it has happened after upgrading **Android Studio**, It can be caused by an out of date buildtool, Update `Android SDK BuildTools`

Answer (score 0):

For **Mac** users

1. open **/Users/username/.gradle/wrapper/dists**
2. Check the latest **gradle-4.4-all** inside that directory
3. Use the latest version and put it to **gradle-wrapper.properties** in Android Studio Project

In my case I was using `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip` that is why I get the issue.

I change it to **distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip** and just sync again

Answer (score 0):

Sometime problem is gradle wrapper file inside your project file. Open your current project gradle file and delete gradle wrapper.zip file and then sync project this will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was in this line:

```
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

My project used a third-party plugin, that is incompatible with the newest gradle plugin version. So updating plugins versions may help to solve the issue.

Comment: which plugin was it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue,
I opened the file:
my-project/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties,
replaced the distributionUrl to

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip

I opened the file:
my-project/build.gradle, under buildscript -> dependencies,
replaced the classpath to

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'

Sync the project and worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `gradle` folder , and let `android studio` **download** it again with click on `Sync now` !.

Answer (score 0):

Now, In March-2021,  gradle 3.4.1-all not worked for me, and arise corrpt error. So, I use in `build.gradle (project:)`  the following elements:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }

        maven {
            url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5' // If you use play service 

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This was my scenary: I had to use another Android Studio version (3.2.1) and the Gradle version was 4.6. For that, I downloaded the .zip version of Android Studio. At first it didn't work, even if I created a new project, Gradle wasn't working. But after some research and some help from this posts I did the following:

1. I went to my gradle files route (android-studio\gradle) and
   **deleted** all the gradle-4.6 files.
2. After that I went to **gradle-wrapper.properties** and got the Gradle version that I needed (gradle-4.6-all.zip).
3. I went to the [gradle site](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) and look for the version that I needed.
4. Downloaded and unziped it into my Android Studio's gradle file route, look step 1.
5. I went to Android Studio settings (file/settings/Gradle) and change the option "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)" to **"Use local gradle distribution"**.
6. I selected the route where I downloaded the Gradle version, that's step 4, and applied changes.
7. Just in case, I used the "Invalidate Cache / Restart" option (file/ "Invalidate Cache / Restart").
8. After that I used the "Sync project and Gradle files" and worked!

By the way, I am using Android Studio 3.2.1 zip version. I had the same problem when I tried to create projects with older Android Studio.