# Gradle upgrade is creating bug, but Android Studio won't let me downgrade

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting the following errors when trying to Sync Gradle (66 of these..)

```
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted DataBlock 65615 found in cache 'C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin'.
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted DataBlock 65690 found in cache 'C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin'.
Caused by: org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.CorruptedCacheException: Corrupted DataBlock 65790 found in cache 'C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\journal-1\file-access.bin'.
```

I tried changing the wrapper Gradle properties back to 3.4.1  as suggested in this post [Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442901/gradles-dependency-cache-may-be-corrupt-this-sometimes-occurs-after-a-network)
but then I get an error
`Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.1.1. Current version is 3.4.1.`

from Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
   }
```

from gradle-wrapper properties file:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

I understand it is a Gradle bug, but I can't downgrade...
I feel like I'm in a loop.

**EDIT:**

I erased the .gradle/cahces folder as I was suggested, but all my files have changed, I lost all my code (well, I do have it all on git) into this:

```
  <library name="Gradle: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9@aar">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6c584dc61f346aee5f9679fb72117c91/jars/classes.jar!/" />
      <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/6c584dc61f346aee5f9679fb72117c91/res" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.firebase/firebase-core/16.0.9/d744794686c273d9fe2fdad77ee686c87a47625b/firebase-core-16.0.9-javadoc.jar!/" />
    </JAVADOC>
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

Very frustrating... suggestions?

Comment: Did you try deleting .gradle folder? if  not delete .gradle,.android studio,.android from C:>users>username and after that restart your studio maybe this should fix it

Comment: Delete the whole .gradle folder?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the `.gradle\caches\` folder?

Comment: yes whenever i encounter any bug with studio i usually delete these whole three folders and everything gets fixed automatically.

Comment: Just close your studio and delete these three folders fully which  i stated above and after deletion restart your studio

Comment: working on it, it says more than a day remaining to delete it all!